# Why doesn't Blender 2.8 see my GTX 750 Ti?

Tags: gpu

Windows 7 32-bit
Intel Core i7 
Latest GPU drivers (clean install)
Latest Blender 32-bit build

No matter what I do, my GPU won't show up as an option under system settings. I've tried uninstalling Blender, uninstalling graphics drivers, doing a clean install of drivers, rebooting, and reinstalling Blender. CUDA is showing up in my NVIDIA system info. What gives? How can I see my GPU? After searching for this issue all day, I can guess that I'm one of few people having this issue.

Comment: Using 32 bit Windows is probably a really bad idea... Using a version that is 10 years old is probably another bad idea. It might be behind a lot of problems. Even though it should work, I can see how Blender might not get tested enough on 32 bit systems and there could probably be a greater chance to have more unfixed bugs on those. It might be a good time to update the OS.

Comment: Martin, you were exactly right. Absolutely no problems with 64-bit. Thanks for the input.